# How do I pass variables to Cloud Code from Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have successfully figured out push notifications in Cloud Code in the basic sense.  I can send a test message from my app and it shows up on my phone.

But I don't understand how to change the values of request.params.message in my Cloud Code.

Also, what I have below causes a Cloud Code error of "invalid type for key message, expected String, but got array." What array?

In case it isn't clear, I am trying to send a push notification to users who subscribe to a particular channel.

My Swift code:

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse
    import Bolts

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var channels = "B08873"
    var minyanID = "bethel08873"
    var message = "This is a test message."



    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject( (minyanID), forKey:"channels")
    currentInstallation.addUniqueObject(message, forKey: "message")

    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()


}

@IBAction func sendPush(sender: AnyObject) {

    if minyanID == channels {


        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("alertUser", withParameters: [channels:message], block: {
            (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if ( error === nil) {
                NSLog("Rates: \(result) ")
            }
            else if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("error")
            }
        });


    }



}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

My Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("alertUser", function(request,response){ 

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var theMessage = request.params.channels; 
    var theChannel = request.params.message; 

    query.equalTo(theChannel) 

    Parse.Push.send({ 
    where: query, 
    data : { alert: theMessage, badge: "Increment", sound: "", } }, 
    { success: function() { response.success()   }, 
    error: function(error) { response.error(err) } 
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are sending `B08873` as key and `This is a test message.` as its value. If you want to send both channel and message key/value pairs you need to do it like this instead:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("alertUser", withParameters: ["channels": channels , "message": message], .....
```

In your Cloud function you should be bale to access these paramerts like this:

```
var theChannels  = request.params.channels;  // returns B08873
var theMessage = request.params.message; // returns This is a test message.
```

Then call the Push function like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    channels: [ theChannels ],
    data: {
    alert: theMessage ,
    badge: "Increment"
    }}, {
        success: function() {
        response.success();
   },
   error: function(error) {
       response.error(error);   
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...I'm much closer now!  My Cloud Code compiles without errors.  But when I try to trigger the push notification, I now get lots of error notifications about line 14 in my javascript. It says reference error not defined. Line 14, if I'm counting correctly, says success:function()

Comment: Please update your cloud code so I can see what you have done

Comment: Parse.Cloud.define("alertUser", function(request,response){
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
var theMessage = request.params.channels;
var theChannel = request.params.message;
query.equalTo(theChannel)
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data : { 
    alert: theMessage,
      badge: "Increment",
      sound: "",
    }
    }, {
    success: function() {
 response.success()
    //Success
    },
    error: function(error) {
 response.error(err)
    //Oops
    }
  });
});

Comment: See all this more neatly formatted at this link:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13575814/project.pdf

Comment: See my updated answer above. You do not need a query for channels

Comment: Errors are gone!  The test message does appear in the Parse data browser, but it is not pushed to my device.  Any thoughts?  I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: What does the delivery report say ? Can you send any Push notification to your device ? If yes, does your device Installation record has the associated channel ?

Comment: The delivery report says that 0 pushes were sent.  If I change [theChannel] to ["Bethel08873"] and "theMessage" to "This is a test message", then the push goes through to my device. Whether my JS says [theChannel] or ["Bethel08873"], the installation record does record the channel correctly.

Comment: I got it!  I had the wrong variable listed for channel.  But I could not have solved this without you...thank you!